# Recent Lovecraftian video game where the objective was to investigate a town or manor or lighthouse and solve a mystery

Tags: story-identification, video-games

One or two years ago, I came across a modern video game trailer which I now can't remember. The trailer was for a future game that had not yet been released.

It was a detective/mystery game in the style of Lovecraft, which may have had supernatural elements. A British man was narrating the trailer and the game was set in the 1920s or thereabouts, in the US. It looked to be similar to New England, and there was a mystery and maybe a suggestion of ghosts. The aim of the story was to investigate a town or manor or lighthouse and the many people in it to solve some mystery. There seemed to be no monsters.

The game mechanics seemed to be a fixed camera and mouse interacting with characters and objects. The graphics were colourful and stylised. It wasn't dark horror or an FPS.

Comment: Do you recall which platform/s this game was on?

Comment: My first thought was ["Call of Cthulhu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu_(video_game)) but that is definitely a horror FPS...

Comment: Was it a point and click style game? Can you recall anything about the artwork?

Comment: For some reason it reminded me a bit of the Archer TV series style but I can't recall if it was 2D or 3D. It was definitely a bright/warm stylized toony look.

Comment: Do you remember some elements that make you think it was in the style of Lovecraft?

Comment: It was set in the early 20th century, it looked to be similar to New England, there was a mystery and *maybe* a suggestion of ghosts. The aim of the story was to investigate a town or manor and the many people in it to solve some mystery.

Comment: *Alone in the Dark* is definitely Lovecraftian, but that seems to be the only part of that game that matches the question.

Comment: Maybe Lovecraftian is then inaccurate. It wasn't horror. It was the setting that seemed similar. There were no monsters.

Comment: It definitely wasn't out yet when I saw the trailer. It seemed far from release. Maybe on Kickstarter or through a similar program. But not 100% sure.

Comment: all of your clarification should be added to the question itself

Comment: Finally found it, sorry for the misremembered details. Overall it's pretty correct I think. I added it to the question as an edit

Comment: @dubious To mark it as solved, you can post it as an answer, and then check the "accept" icon next to it. Otherwise it won't be correctly identified as solved by the website automated system, may be bumped regularly on the frontpage, and appear in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Thanks. It says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: @dubious Ah, I didn't know this limitation. I don't know its rationale, but my first impression is that I don't like it. Anyway... thanks for sharing the answer!

Comment: It is propably The Thaumaturge

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been looking for ages and finally found it. It's ***[Foolish Mortals](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1848440/Foolish_Mortals/)*** (2024).

I misremembered a lot of details. Sorry if that was misleading. Thanks for the help.

> Foolish Mortals is a narrative-driven point & click adventure game. Obsessed with finding the lost treasure of Bellemore Manor, Murphy McCallan encounters ghosts, voodoo, and an evil phantom who wants the treasure as their own. If you want to find it, perhaps you’ll have to die too...

Comment: I was going to suggest Goetia, which has similar gameplay and themes, but I was too slow. :)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like *[Call of Cthulhu:  Shadow of the Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Comet)*, a Cthulhu mythos adventure game from 1993.  I think it was the first video game explicitly set in the mythos (and made with a license from Chaosium, back when people thought that Chaosium actually had the gaming rights to Lovecraft's work).  The atmosphere of the game is really well done (at least for the first two thirds of the game; I found that last day of the three-day timeline disappointing), but technically it was pretty typical for adventure games of the time.  It's readily available via Steam and GOG now.

Here is one trailer for it.

The trailer starts right off with a sinister lighthouse; there are also several large New England houses occupied by cultists in the game.  Several of the characters, including the in the trailer, are British.

Comment: " (and made with a license from Chaosium, back when people thought that Chaosium actually had the gaming rights to Lovecraft's work)". Sounds like there's an interesting story here

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the game. It was a trailer for a future release I saw in 2022 or 2023